# What does a type have to be constrained to before it can be assigned "null"?

Tags: scala, types, null, scala-2.8

```
trait Link[This] {
    var next:This = null
}
```

gives "type mismatch; found: Null(null) required: This"

So presumably I need to tell the type checker that This is going to be a type that can be assigned null. How do I do this?

(If there's a site I should be reading first before asking questions like this, please point me at it. I'm currently part-way through the preprint of the 2nd Ed of Programming In Scala)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to constrain `This` to be a superclass of `Null` - which is the way of telling the compiler that `null` is a valid value for that type. (In fact, thinking about `Any`, `AnyRef` and `AnyVal` only muddles the problem - just ask the compiler for what you want!)

```
trait Link[This >: Null] {
  var next:This = null
}
```

However, I would suggest that you avoid using `null`, you could use `Option[This]` and affect `None` - such a construction will allow you to use pattern matching, and is a very strong statement that clients using this field should expect it to maybe have no value.

```
trait Link[This] {
  var next:Option[This] = None
}
```

Comment: Quite right about the Option and it will go that way eventually. But this is a step in refactoring some code originally in Java, and there's too many uses of null to do that right now

Answer (score 0):

```
trait Link {
  var next:This = null
}
```

This should work. Is there a specific reason that you want to need to parameterize the trait with a type?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you assume that the `Link` class is only as complex as the snippet he has written?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason - this is mixed in to another class and I'm constructing a linked list of that class.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought, which didn't work.  I'm not sure why.

```
trait Link[This <: AnyRef] { // Without the type bound, it's Any
    var next: This = null
}
```

When worse comes to worst, there's always casting:

```
trait Link[This <: AnyRef] {
    var next: This = null.asInstanceOf[This]
}
```

With the cast, you no longer need the type bound for this trait to compile, although you might want it there for other reasons.

Comment: I believe that the reason is that "extends `AnyRef`" and "accepts `null` as a value" are logically distinct - one could see the fact that every currently possible type in the JVM either satisfies or denies both as an implementation detail.

Comment: It didn't work because there is the idea that some classes of `AnyRef` could be forced to be not null.  So you need `trait Link[This >: Null <: AnyRef]`.  But nothing in `AnyVal` is a superclass of `Null` anyway, so `Link[This >: Null]` is enough.